# Erro ao mostra a imagem com GD

Tags: php, gd

Estou tentando exibir uma imagem em PNG na tela do navegador do cliente usando PHP, mas aparece apenas uma tela preta com um quadrinho no centro.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Eis o meu código:

```
<?php

        $file  = "img.png";
        $width = 500;
        $height= 500;

        list($width_origin,$height_origin) = getimagesize($file);
        $ratio = $width_origin / $height_origin;

        if ($width/$height > $ratio) {
            $width = $height * $ratio;
        }else{
            $height = $width / $ratio;
        }

        $image_final  = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $imagem_origin= imagecreatefrompng($file);
        imagecopyresampled($image_final,$imagem_origin,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$width_origin,$height_origin);
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($image_final,"imagem_nova.png");


    ?>
```

Comment: Qual seria o erro mostrado? Existe algo nos logs?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: amigo sou novo no php e na programação mais aparece a tela preta com um quadrinho no centro

Comment: Amigo, editei a sua pergunta para tentar evitar o seu fechamento (já tem 4 votos negativos e 4 de fechamento). Se não fosse pela resposta do colega abaixo, eu também teria fechado ela, pois olhando para o seu texto, não entendi o que é que você estava perguntando (só entendi com a resposta), uma vez que você não estava perguntando nada mesmo. Você apenas disse que deu erro (sem dizer qual foi o erro) e nada falou sobre o código ou sobre o que você está tentando fazer. [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Bem, editei a sua pergunta para colocar algum texto e talvez com isso ela possa permanecer aberta. Mas da próxima vez, tente formulá-la melhor para evitar aborrecimentos desse tipo, que são muito comuns neste site, e se esforce em descrever bem o problema que você está tendo e preze por uma boa redação. Há muitas perguntas por aqui que seriam boas, mas acabam fechadas porque quem a postou não soube se expressar direito e os demais usuários não entenderam a pergunta. Fica a dica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você colocar o segundo parâmetro em `imagepng` ele não vai exibir e sim salvar, é como está descrito na documentação http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

> If not set or NULL, the raw image stream will be outputted directly.
>
> Ou seja se o segundo parâmetro não for definido ou o for `NULL` ele irá exibir, caso contrário ele irá salvar para um arquivo.

Então sempre que tiver dúvida, dê uma pesquisada na documentação e leia como usar cada parâmetro e veja os exemplos. No caso o seu código deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

$file  = "img.png";
$width = 500;
$height= 500;

list($width_origin, $height_origin) = getimagesize($file);

$ratio = $width_origin / $height_origin;

if ($width/$height > $ratio) {
    $width = $height * $ratio;
}else{
    $height = $width / $ratio;
}

$image_final  = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$imagem_origin= imagecreatefrompng($file);
imagecopyresampled($image_final,$imagem_origin, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_origin, $height_origin);
header("Content-Type: image/png");

imagepng($image_final); //Exibe a imagem
```

Se deseja exibir e salvar ao mesmo tempo, pode usar vários métodos, como salvar para um stream ou arquivo diretamente:

- Usando `readfile`:

  ```
  if (imagepng($image_final, $file)) //salva para um arquivo
  {
      header("Content-Type: image/png");
      readfile($file);
  } else {
      echo 'Erro ao salvar';
  }
  ```
- `fopen`+`stream_get_contents`

  Esse é um pouco mais complicado, mas se precisar fazer alguma manipulação no stream talvez seja interessante usá-lo.

  ```
  $handle = fopen($handle, 'wb');

  if (!$handle) {
      die('Erro ao abrir o arquivo para escrita');
  }

  if (imagepng($image_final, $handle)) //salva para um arquivo
  {
      header("Content-Type: image/png");
      echo stream_get_contents($handle);
  } else {
      echo 'Erro ao salvar';
  }

  fclose($handle);
  ```

### O que cada parâmetro faz:

A função basicamente é

```
bool imagepng ( resource $image [, mixed $to [, int $quality [, int $filters ]]] )
```

- `$image`

  Deve ser um *resource* de uma imagem, retornado pelas funções de criação de imagem, por exemplo `imagecreatetruecolor()`, `imagecreatefrompng()`, etc.
- `$to`

  O caminho ou um stream aberto (que será automaticamente fechado quando a função retorna) para gravar o arquivo. Se não definido ou for `NULL`, a imagem será exibida no output.
- `$quality`

  Nível de compactação: se 0 (não há compactação) até 9.
- `$filters`

  Permite reduzir o tamanho do arquivo PNG. Isto é um campo de *bitmask* o qual talvez possa definir qualquer combinação das [**constantes `PNG_FILTER_XXX`**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/image.constants.php).  Se usar `PNG_NO_FILTER` ou `PNG_ALL_FILTERS` ou usar eles respectivamente irá desabilitar ou habilitar todos os filtros.

Comment: Entendi sim ali está com o 2 parâmetro mais sem ele igual não aparece a imagem, só aparece a tela preta e um quadrado no centro pequeno

Comment: sim existe o segundo parâmetro  funcionou, será que o servidor embutido no php7 suporta essa biblioteca

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwln2qIiY0sYXzh3YkRDRTlvck0 olha se deu aí. É o print

Comment: Aparece todo o código da imagem com várias interrogações

Comment: PNG  IHDR�8"�� IDATx��i�$G�%�T�����:P@c�{zv���B!��/�P(2��N�4�P��Wn����4�="� =M!?���nn��O�M���7+����-4��e�o|��M}P������;?/n��|

Comment: só a primeira linha coloquei

Comment: @RogerMoraesdeMoura tem algum espaçamento antes de PNG IHDR?

Comment: �PNG  IHDR está assim

Comment: só com um [] no meio dele

Comment: Pois é se olhar bem está assim ?PNG [] IHDR se contar isso como espaço tem um depois do png e um antes do IHDR

Comment: @RogerMoraesdeMoura faz assim, troca `/*header("Content-Type: image/png");*/` por `header("Content-Type: text/plain");` (remova os `/*` e `*/` também) e então verifica se tem algum espaço ou quebra de linha, tipo um espaçamento ou algo assim

Comment: abri com o gedit tem um espaço grande depois do PNG

Comment: @RogerMoraesdeMoura e antes nada né? Então me manda o arquivo que usou em `$file  = "img.png";` pelo googledrive